# Set the opacity of raster layer based on the values in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have raster data of daily snowfall depth that I would like to overlay on an animated map using mapboxGL-JS, I am using JS rather than uploading the images to studio because I would like to have a lot of them to change daily using my script.

My goal is to set the raster opacity so that the only lower snow depth values are transparent. However, I can't find good documentation on how to do this.

I have cropped our images as a gif to add to the map as shown below, and I think I can set the opacity in the "paint" value but have yet to find the right settings:

```
map.addSource('Snow_1', {
            'type': 'image',
            'url': 'MY_SNOW_LAYER.gif',
            'coordinates': [
            [-120.000000, 50.000000],
            [-100.000000, 50.000000],
            [-100.000000, 40.000000],
            [-120.000000, 40.000000]
            ]
        });
map.addLayer({
             'id': 'Snow_layer_1',
             'type': 'raster',
             'source': 'Snow_1',
             'paint': {
                        'raster-fade-duration': 0,
                        'raster-opacity': 0.75,// change to data-driven!
              }
        });
```